regexreplace multiple columns for football data
I've been trying without success to import using google sheets to scrape the various team table data from the url's https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024/  and https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024/opp.htm
I found this code from another post.
ImportXML XPath issue using Google Sheets on a simple web scraping query
It is so close to my need but I've been unable adapt it to similar data from the same website.
The query portion pulls the correct unparsed data.
QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024/");"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'exp_pts_rush'")

So I believe my misunderstanding of REGEXREPLACE is the issue.
Any help is appreciated
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024/");"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'exp_pts_rush'");"></td>";">0</td>"));".+ranker.+?>(.+?)<.+team.+([A-Z]{3}).+g.+?>(.+?)<.+?rush.+?>(.+?)<.+?rush.+?>(.+?)<.+?rush.+?>(.+?)<.+?rush.+?>(.+?)<.+?rush.+?>(.+?)<.+?rush.+?>(.+?)<.+?fum.+?>(.+?)<.+?exp.+";"$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;$9;$10;$11"));"select * WHERE NOT Col1 contains '<'");";"))


I hope to a result like this.


As an alternative, you can get the related data with this script;
function getTable() {
  var url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024/";
 
  try {
    var options = {
        "method" : "GET",
        'headers': {
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.5359.172 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.43'
        },
        'muteHttpExceptions': true
      };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
    
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      var html = response.getContentText();
      html = html.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
      
      var tablesMatch = html.match(/<tbody(.*?)<\/tbody>/gm);
      
      if (tablesMatch && tablesMatch.length > 1) {
        var myTable = tablesMatch[2];
        //Logger.log(myTable);
        var doc = XmlService.parse(myTable); 
      
        var rows = doc.getDescendants().filter(function(c) {
          var element = c.asElement();
          return element && element.getName() == "tr";
        });

        var data = rows.slice(0).map(function(row) {
          return row.getChildren("td").map(function(cell) {
            return cell.getValue();
          });
        });

        Logger.log(data); 
        
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clearContents()

        var headers=[['Tm','G','Att','Yds','TD','Lng','Y/A','Y/G','Fmb','EXP']];

        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1, headers.length, headers[0].length).setValues(headers).setFontWeight("bold");

        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

        } else {
          Browser.msgBox("No tables found");
        } 
      } else {
        Browser.msgBox( "Error: Cannot connect to URL . HTTP response code: " + response.getResponseCode());
        } 
      }
      catch (e) {
        Browser.msgBox(e);
        return;   
      }
}

.
The below table shows the output on the sheet;
.



Tm
G
Att
Yds
TD
Lng
Y/A
Y/G
Fmb
EXP




Green Bay Packers
2
74
424
1
34
5.7
212
3
2.89


Los Angeles Chargers
2
71
395
2
61
5.6
197.5
1
3.82


New Orleans Saints
2
76
370
6
17
4.9
185
1
16.19


Arizona Cardinals
2
65
355
2
41
5.5
177.5
3
11.85


New England Patriots
2
75
355
2
45
4.7
177.5
2
5.47


Washington Commanders
2
65
353
3
40
5.4
176.5
3
11.67


Baltimore Ravens
2
59
336
2
29
5.7
168
1
14.25


Philadelphia Eagles
2
75
330
3
34
4.4
165
2
4.62


Detroit Lions
2
58
302
3
24
5.2
151
0
19.81


Houston Texans
2
62
288
1
18
4.6
144
1
-7.31


San Francisco 49ers
2
63
282
3
24
4.5
141
3
1.92


Pittsburgh Steelers
2
77
278
0
20
3.6
139
2
-13.26


Tennessee Titans
2
54
270
2
26
5
135
2
5.65


Minnesota Vikings
2
50
257
1
25
5.1
128.5
4
4.92


Jacksonville Jaguars
2
47
255
2
33
5.4
127.5
3
-2.01


Indianapolis Colts
2
40
244
2
29
6.1
122
3
14.3


Atlanta Falcons
2
50
241
0
19
4.8
120.5
2
-4.74


Buffalo Bills
2
59
238
4
49
4
119
2
0.33


Kansas City Chiefs
2
52
221
2
21
4.3
110.5
1
4.23


Miami Dolphins
2
59
220
1
17
3.7
110
0
-6.94


Cleveland Browns
2
48
218
2
36
4.5
109
2
3.86


New York Giants
2
43
203
1
22
4.7
101.5
2
0.49


Seattle Seahawks
2
52
192
3
34
3.7
96
1
-5.81


Tampa Bay Buccaneers
2
53
182
1
31
3.4
91
2
-5.94


Dallas Cowboys
2
46
170
1
12
3.7
85
2
0.43


New York Jets
2
43
169
2
30
3.9
84.5
1
0.25


Denver Broncos
2
44
163
1
23
3.7
81.5
2
-3.18


Chicago Bears
2
44
155
1
24
3.5
77.5
3
-1.48


Carolina Panthers
2
38
148
1
23
3.9
74
1
-3.27


Cincinnati Bengals
2
38
144
1
16
3.8
72
6
3.84


Los Angeles Rams
2
43
136
2
12
3.2
68
1
-1.84


Las Vegas Raiders
2
39
98
1
12
2.5
49
3
-21.03




This works great! But on first look I'm unsure how to change table output to passing data for instance. I'm a newbie with scrips but this is wonderful jump start. Thank you!

If the solution works for you, you can upvote by clicking the up-arrow button and also Accept the answer.


Here's one approach which you may test out:
=let(Σ,tocol(split(choosecols(importxml("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024","//*[@id='all_rushing']"),3),char(10))),
 filter(substitute(split(regexreplace(Σ,"([a-z])( )([A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z])","$1$3")," "),""," "),regexmatch(Σ,"^\d+ ")))


semicolon-based
=let(Σ;tocol(split(choosecols(importxml("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2024";"//*[@id='all_rushing']");3);char(10)));
 filter(substitute(split(regexreplace(Σ;"([a-z])( )([A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z])";"$1$3");" ");"";" ");regexmatch(Σ;"^\d+ ")))


Thanks Rockin. This looks ideal however, I get a parse error. I'm clueless regarding the ' cyclone emoji ' in your code. I've tried @,&,* and searched the ascii table as well. What am I missing?

could be your sheet locale uses semicolon convention

Based on similar formulas we would use a semicolon here in the US, but no luck so far. But I will try later tonight.  thanks again

Updated semicolon-based formula in the answer. And US sheet locale uses comma-based style

That was perfect.! But I want many similar tables like "all_passing" which has more that twice the number of columns and I get wrapped results. How can I change this to allow for more columns. Or ideally have a formula that is variable?

rockin.. I've spent hours trying figure out why some data tables start wrapping at column U and others column V.    'all_passing' and 'all_team_stats' respectively.

The above formula is exclusively created and tested for all_rushing; If it's not working for other parameter tables, then most likely the formula needs adjustments accordingly. Free free to post the question again and hopefully someone else might come up with the ideal variable formula you are looking for...
